# Button to fill textbox from selected datagrid row

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a problem with the following this vb thing looks a lot like what I am trying to make: [Clicking on a datagrid row and displaying its contents in textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002479/clicking-on-a-datagrid-row-and-displaying-its-contents-in-textboxes).
Can someone please shed some light on these columns:

```
  ,[empLastName]
  ,[empFirstName]
  ,[empExtension]
  ,[empEmail]
  ,[empOfficeCode]
  ,[empReportsTo]
  ,[empJobTitle]
  ,[empActive]
```

I need to take out all the valves from it to a multi-line text box by the click of a button called SelectedCells.

Here is the button code so far, and yes it does more than only take the row data to a textbox:

```
private void selectedCellsButton_Click_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                Int32 selectedCellCount =
                    dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
                if (selectedCellCount > 0)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.AreAllCellsSelected(true))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("All cells are selected", "Selected Cells");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Text.StringBuilder sb =
                            new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                        for (int i = 0;
                            i < selectedCellCount; i++)
                        {
                            sb.Append("Row: ");
                            sb.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex
                                .ToString());
                            sb.Append(", Column: ");
                            sb.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex
                                .ToString());
                            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                        sb.Append("Total: " + selectedCellCount.ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Selected Cells");
                        double[] list = new double[9];


                          Cvalve.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["empNumber"].Value.ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If someone can point out where it goes wrong, and maybe point me in right direction with some guidance in the code itself.

Comment: I have no idea what you want or what you do. If you want to do what your title says, why not do it? Why bother with selected cells and a Messagbox?? The VB code's answer you mention is rather clear. I see no similarity to your code, exept for the last line. Repeat that for all columns, skip the rest and you're done! Or explain better (and with corrected spelling, please) what you want.

Comment: the messagebox is just done so user has a convermation with cells an in witch row are selected
what i want to do is take the valves from the selecte rows to a multi line text box but i had found some pepole who did it the other way and found some thing that does not work give error in column names, but problem is that the gridview has the same column names and database columns are called exactly the same

Comment: if i do what you explaned it give back this exception : The index is out of range. These must not be negative and must be less than the size of the collection. on each line

Comment: OK. Edit your question and show us the part that throws the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];

Cvalve.Text  = row.Cells["empNumber"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;    
Cvalve.Text += row.Cells["empLastName"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;    
//...    
Cvalve.Text += row.Cells["empJobTitle"].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;    
Cvalve.Text += row.Cells["empActive"].Value.ToString() ;
```

?

You need to decide, which row you want to show. If you have the `DataGridView.SelectionMode`set to `CellSelect` the user can select cells without a row being selected. Then you could for example use

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex];
```

instead to display the data from the row of the first selected cell.

Comment: Gets The index is out of range. These must not be negative and must be less than the size of the collection on first line.

Comment: next one is cant find column now the row is selected in the gridview its self ether by user click or by a button.

Comment: fixed it up the column names need to be taken out of the lines and colunm index like 1 trough in my case 8 needed to be put in now it does put in all the columnes of a selected row.

Comment: Good, that you got it working. Just a note: You __can__ access Cells by their column indices __or__ names; you just need to get the names right! This can be very useful, especially when the number or order of the selected columns change..